Help buying reserve Air conditioner capacitors
I wanted to buy a reserve capacitor for my Air Conditioner in case the one it has fails i can change it myself with minimal downtime and no expensive "emergency" to a tech that will charge me 10X the price of a capacitor ...
After taking the panel out I noticed a strange setup, seem there are two capacitors connected in series, see picture below:

Here are close up pics of the capacitors labels


it looks like they set this machine with:

dual run capacitor 35+5 MFD
single run capacitor 7.5 MFD

So the question is: Do I need two?
I'm leaning towards getting just one dual run 40+5 MFD

Who's to say your replacement capacitor won't age just sitting on the shelf?

there must be a reason why they are not using the 5MFD part of the existing capacitor

They are not in series. Looks like the yellow wire is a common, and the blue wire is at the same potential. Only if the yellow wire was not present would the capacitors truly be in series.

@Harper-ReinstateMonica  Who's to say your replacement capacitor won't age just sitting on the shelf yes everything ages for sure, but indoors in a temp controlled environment should last a lot longer that outdoors exposed to the elements, and the ones in this machine probably have more than 5 years.

Don't do that.
Find the wiring diagram. I think you'll find that the unit calls for one 35+5 MFD capacitor (meaning one can with two capacitors in it, a 35 and a 5.) I don't think you'll find a 7.5 MFD capacitor in the wiring diagram at all.
Look at the 35+5 capacitor can. Only one of the internal capacitors is connected, which is probably the 35 MFD. I think someone installed the 7.5 MFD as a substitute for the 5 MFD. Maybe there was a hard-start situation. Maybe a more powerful blower motor was installed that required 7.5 instead of 5 MFD.
Those capacitors do not appear to be in series.
WARNING: Capacitors in series do not add their capacitance. You compute the result like resistors in parallel. If you install a 35 MFD in series with a 7.5 MFD, the resulting capacitance is 6.18 MFD. Won't work.

7.5 will be the run capacitor, not start.

the blower motor seem to the original, at least the screws do not look to have ever been removed ... with the info you are giving me. I get a feeling the 5 MFD went bad at some point and the tech that did the repair just did that workaround

If the manufacturer used two components, it's because they wanted a value they couldn't easily get with one. I would not change this gratuitously. Caps are cheap.

By the duct tape used to hold the smaller cap, I'm convinced this is not coming this way from manufacturer

Well, if you can figure out which cap it's in series with, I believe two caps in series is 1/(1/c1+1/c2)
